# How can I protect myself from a zip bomb?

Tags: java, python, security, compression, zip

I just read about [zip bombs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_bomb), i.e. zip files that contain very large amount of highly compressible data (00000000000000000...).

When opened they fill the server's disk.

How can I detect a zip file is a zip bomb **before** unzipping it?

**UPDATE** Can you tell me how is this done in Python or Java?

Comment: The compression ratio can be smth like 1000 to 1 - not only it consumes a lot of disk space but also takes long time to write the output.

Comment: [Related question about gzip and bzip2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13622706/how-to-protect-myself-from-a-gzip-or-bzip2-bomb).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try this in Python:

```py
import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile('a_file.zip') as z
    print(f'total files size={sum(e.file_size for e in z.infolist())}')
```

Comment: At least with gzip I think the uncompressed size might not be in the header (so it might work with zip, but not with .tar.gz)

Comment: @tonfa, thanks for mentioning that zipfile doesn't handle gnu zip format.

Comment: IIRC, Zip standard (and let's face it, if you want to cause a DoS, you are necessarily going to follow standards) allows certain sizes to be elided from the central directory and entry headers.

Comment: The most famous zip bomb will pass this test because the first level is not very big. You need to check ZIP depth (ZIP inside ZIP) also.

Comment: @ZZ Coder, hmm that's true. Tom Hawtin - tackline's solution is better in case you decompress all levels at once.

Comment: @Kevin, you ask if the unzipping procedure does actually verify the "size" attribute? Good point. If not, then the above code can "fail", of course.

Comment: @SAN3 check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#entries()

Comment: What if you include a zip bomb within a normal zip?

Comment: @ZZCoder When you don't decompress the ZIP file recursively (meaning decompressing inner ZIP files of the initial ZIP) you are not affected by multi-layered zip bombs, are you? I can' really imagine why someone would want to decompress recursively, but I guess there will be some use-case for that...

Comment: Maybe it will be useful to someone, ZipFile can accept not only the path to the archive, but also any file-like object. You can check the archive without even saving

Answer (score 25):

Zip is, erm, an "interesting" format. A robust solution is to stream the data out, and stop when you have had enough. In Java, use `ZipInputStream` rather than `ZipFile`. The latter also requires you to store the data in a temporary file, which is also not the greatest of ideas.

Comment: This is old, I know, but still: How come it matters whether you're reading a file or an input stream? To my understanding, you can read both types using an iterative approach, stopping when you've read a certain amount of bytes or reached a certain number of iterations.

Comment: @AsgerSkovVelling It is quite old. `ZipFile` requires you to download the entire thing to read the directory which is at the end. (Zip was design for archiving not retrieval. Files can be streamed out, and then when all the indexes are known, the directory written.) Perhaps the worst problem is that you need all of the archive available all at once. There is an additional check you need to make sure that the entire compressed archive isn't too large. Also, if you read the directory then it may direct you to read the same file data repeatedly. Files can even overlap.

Comment: @AsgerSkovVelling Oh, and there's also the issue of Gifar, which followed a series a vulnerabilities in IE and Flash. If you go through the directory, the front of the file may be something else. `ZipInputStream` will check the file starts with magic number for a local header. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gifar

Answer (score 13):

Reading over the description on Wikipedia -

Deny any compressed files that contain compressed files.
     Use [ZipFile.entries()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#entries()) to retrieve a list of files, then [ZipEntry.getName()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html#getName()) to find the file extension.
Deny any compressed files that contain files over a set size, or the size can not be determined at startup.
     While iterating over the files use [ZipEntry.getSize()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html#getSize()) to retrieve the file size.

Comment: `getSize` lies. The the size claimed in the directory, an entirely difference size in the local header and then a different size again when you actually come to decompress. Also, I don't know what files types are compressed (images?) and it's typical for files to be sent over a compressed link (HTTP often has gzip compression).

Answer (score 6):

Don't allow the upload process to write enough data to fill up the disk, ie solve the problem, not just one possible cause of the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Check a zip header first :)

Comment: check the comments in Nick Dandoulakis's answer

Answer (score 4):

If the ZIP decompressor you use can provide the data on original and compressed size you can use that data. Otherwise start unzipping and monitor the output size - if it grows too much cut it loose.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are not using your system drive for temp storage. I am not sure if a virusscanner will check it if it encounters it.

Also you can look at the information inside the zip file and retrieve a list of the content. How to do this depends on the utility used to extract the file, so you need to provide more information here