# How to use Archive::Extract safely - againist zip bomb or similar?

Tags: perl, compression

Problem outline:

- need allow upload ZIP files (and `tgz` and more compressed directory trees) via web-from
- the zip files should be extracted for their content handling
- planning to use [Archive::Extract](http://perldoc.perl.org/Archive/Extract.html) for the extracting
- here are things like [ZIP BOMBS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_bomb) and like...

From the manual

> Archive::Extract can use either pure perl modules or command line
>   programs under the hood. Some of the pure perl modules (like
>   Archive::Tar and Compress::unLZMA) take the entire contents of the
>   archive into memory, which may not be feasible on your system.
>   Consider setting the global variable $Archive::Extract::PREFER_BIN to
>   1 , which will prefer the use of command line programs and won't
>   consume so much memory.

The questions are:

- When I set the `$Archive::Extract::PREFER_BIN = 1` - i'm enough protected againist ZIP-BOMB like things?
- $Archive::Extract::PREFER_BIN protect me againist much memory usage - but, the standard `unzip`, `tar -z` `unrar` binaries are safe againist zip bomb like attacks?
- If not - how to handle safely uploaded compressed `directory tree`? (so here is not only one  file inside the e.g `zip archive`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$Archive::Extract::PREFER_BIN = 1 doesn't protect you against zip bombs, you are passing the problem to the binary unzip tool of your system.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13622706/how-to-protect-myself-from-a-gzip-or-bzip2-bomb) may helps you. I like the idea of running a second process with ulimit.