# http request with timeout, maximum size and connection pooling

Tags: python, http, timeout, connection-pooling, max-size

I'm looking for a way in Python (2.7) to do HTTP requests with 3 requirements:

- timeout (for reliability)
- content maximum size (for security)
- connection pooling (for performance)

I've checked quite every python HTTP librairies, but none of them meet my requirements. For instance:

**urllib2: good, but no pooling**

```
import urllib2
import json

r = urllib2.urlopen('https://github.com/timeline.json', timeout=5)
content = r.read(100+1)
if len(content) > 100: 
    print 'too large'
    r.close()
else:
    print json.loads(content)

r = urllib2.urlopen('https://github.com/timeline.json', timeout=5)
content = r.read(100000+1)
if len(content) > 100000: 
    print 'too large'
    r.close()
else:
    print json.loads(content)
```

**requests: no max size**

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://github.com/timeline.json', timeout=5, stream=True)
r.headers['content-length'] # does not exists for this request, and not safe
content = r.raw.read(100000+1)
print content # ARF this is gzipped, so not the real size
print json.loads(content) # content is gzipped so pretty useless
print r.json() # Does not work anymore since raw.read was used
```

**urllib3: never got the "read" method working, even with a 50Mo file ...**

**httplib: httplib.HTTPConnection is not a pool (only one connection)**

I can hardly belive that urllib2 is the best HTTP library I can use ! So if anyone knows what librairy can do this or how to use one of the previous librairy ...

**EDIT:**

The best solution I found thanks to Martijn Pieters (StringIO does not slow down even for huge files, where str addition does a lot).

```
r = requests.get('https://github.com/timeline.json', stream=True)
size = 0
ctt = StringIO()


for chunk in r.iter_content(2048):
    size += len(chunk)
    ctt.write(chunk)
    if size > maxsize:
        r.close()
        raise ValueError('Response too large')

content = ctt.getvalue()
```

Comment: At the `ctt.write(chunk)` line I get a `TypeError: string argument expected, got 'bytes'`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do it with `requests` just fine; but you need to know that the `raw` object is part of the `urllib3` guts and make use of the extra arguments the [`HTTPResponse.read()` call](http://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/helpers.html#urllib3.response.HTTPResponse.read) supports, which lets you specify you want to read *decoded* data:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://github.com/timeline.json', timeout=5, stream=True)

content = r.raw.read(100000+1, decode_content=True)
if len(content) > 100000:
    raise ValueError('Too large a response')
print content
print json.loads(content)
```

Alternatively, you can set the `decode_content` flag on the `raw` object before reading:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://github.com/timeline.json', timeout=5, stream=True)

r.raw.decode_content = True
content = r.raw.read(100000+1)
if len(content) > 100000:
    raise ValueError('Too large a response')
print content
print json.loads(content)
```

If you don't like reaching into `urllib3` guts like that, use the [`response.iter_content()`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.iter_content) to iterate over the decoded content in chunks; this uses the underlying `HTTPResponse` too (using the [`.stream()` generator version](http://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/helpers.html?highlight=decode_content#urllib3.response.HTTPResponse.stream):

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://github.com/timeline.json', timeout=5, stream=True)

maxsize = 100000
content = ''
for chunk in r.iter_content(2048):
    content += chunk
    if len(content) > maxsize:
        r.close()
        raise ValueError('Response too large')

print content
print json.loads(content)
```

There is of subtle difference here in how compressed data sizes are handled here; `r.raw.read(100000+1)` will only ever read 100k bytes of compressed data; the uncompressed data is tested against your max size. The `iter_content()` method will read more uncompressed data *in the rare case the compressed stream is **larger** than the uncompressed data*.

Neither method allows `r.json()` to work; the `response._content` attribute isn't set by these; you can do so manually of course. But since the `.raw.read()` and `.iter_content()` calls already give you access to the content in question, there is really no need.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to compare which method works the best (in particular, which one limits the real size not the downloaded one): `urllib2` does not accept compression, `r.raw.read` compare the gzipped size, and `r.iter_content` compare the real size but really slow down the code (perhaps a stream would make it faster).

Comment: @AurélienLambert: how much `r.iter_content()` slows down the code depends entirely on the size of the chunks read; a small chunk size necessitates more loop iterations. And it operates on a stream *already*.

Comment: The `content += chunk` slow it down due to python str non mutability. StringIO.StringIO solved it.

Comment: Yes, I contemplated using a list instead, then `''.join()` at the end, but `StringIO()` encapsulates that nicely.

Comment: You can't use timeout for a stream. **Documentation: On streaming requests, the timeout only applies to the connection attempt**

Comment: @AdrianB: so? You *can* use `timeout` but it only applies to the connection attempt.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, and for me is a big problem

Comment: @Adrian: did my answer lead you to believe that it did? I'm happy to clarify on that. You can wrap this in a signal handler that cuts off the request if it takes too long still, for example.

Comment: @Adrian: for example: [Timeout function if it takes too long to finish](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2281850)

Comment: For anyone trying this on Python3 note that you'll need `content = b''` +1

Comment: @AurélienLambert: beware of [gzip bombs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13622706/4279) -- I don't know whether `decode_content=True` above makes the code susceptible. Unrelated: you can if you wish to [read compressed data using `urllib2` if you read it into memory as in your case](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3947241/4279). [Python 3 code allows to stream gzipped content](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26435241/4279).

Comment: @AdrianB: the only non-async.io portable [http library that limits the total connection and read timeouts (that I know of) is `pycurl` (that has horrendous API)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9548869/4279). The alternative is to close the connection using `Timer()` e.g., if `r` is `urllib.request.urlopen()` response then `Timer(timeout, r.fp.raw._sock.shutdown, [socket.SHUT_RDWR])` can enforce the total read timeout (if various `.close()` methods were idempotent here then there would be a less ugly without reaching into guts way to implement the timeout).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: `decode_content=True` allows for the exact same decompression handling as would be used for the `response.content` or `response.text` properties (loading the whole content as one binary or Unicode string). All decompression is handled in urllib3 in either case, no protection against a decompression bomb is included in that.

Comment: If the response is gzipped, does it unpack the content block by block?

Comment: @daisy: yes, compressed content is decompressed as you stream.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Saving chunk content as bytes to `content = b''` will still eat up memory. The `StringIO` option is an interesting alternative, but requires an additional module import. Probably easier to add up the chunk length? So `size = 0` instead of `content = b''`, and then `size += len(chunk)` instead of `content += chunk` and then check `if size > maxsize`. Could also initially check `if int(r.headers.get('Content-Length')) > maxsize`, in which case you don't have to download chunks at all if Content-Length is actually set.

Comment: @kregus: `StringIO` will require the same amount of memory, it won't flush to a disk. You are free to handle the chunks as they come in instead of storing them in memory; you could write them to disk for example. Chunked responses do not always have a Content-Length header, one of the reasons this question was posted in the first place (*does not exists for this request, and not safe*.