# Python Infinite Integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory, integer, long-integer

Python 3 integers have [unlimited precision](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex). In practice, this is limited by a computer's memory.

Consider the followng code:

```
i = 12345
while True:
    i = i * 123
```

This will obviously fail. But what will be the result of this? The entire RAM (and the page file) filled with this one integer (except for the space occupied by other processes)?

Or is there a safeguard to catch this before it gets that far?

Comment: You will hit a MemoryError

Comment: So, most of RAM and pagefile will be overwritten?

Comment: Depends on what the OS allows, and whether `i` started off as zero or not.

Comment: A non-zero `i`. So how far do you think this will get before a typical Windows system considers the process a runaway and throws a MemoryError?

Comment: @coding4fun Read this: http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-doesnt-python-release-the-memory-when-i-delete-a-large-object.htm

Comment: So, interestingly, there may be some optimization on integers (exponent stored separately?)  I started running your loop, and memory allocation hasn't budged.

Comment: I stopped it and looked, and it's just an efficiency issue.  I suppose if you want to eat up RAM as well as CPU, you might want to shift more than one bit at a time.

Comment: I changed some numbers in the loop to mix things up.

Comment: Yeah, `i **= 2` visibly eats into memory; `i *= 2` not so much.

Comment: @PatrickMaupin,  sys.getsizeof does climb, also top shows the process memory climbing but would take an age to hit a MemoryError

Comment: Right, I saw that.  The DOS would be noticed from a CPU perspective long before memory was an issue on most systems.

Comment: Python 2 also has `long` integers.

Comment: article about the windows process limits http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2008/07/21/3092070.aspx

Comment: @PatrickMaupin Could you please clarify what you mean by *DOS*?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check what happens without risking to fill all available memory. You could [set the memory limit explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14024198/4279):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import contextlib
import resource

@contextlib.contextmanager
def limit(limit, type=resource.RLIMIT_AS):
    soft_limit, hard_limit = resource.getrlimit(type)
    resource.setrlimit(type, (limit, hard_limit)) # set soft limit
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        resource.setrlimit(type, (soft_limit, hard_limit)) # restore

with limit(100 * (1 << 20)): # 100MiB
    # do the thing that might try to consume all memory
    i = 1
    while True:
        i <<= 1
```

This code consumes 100% CPU (on a single core) and the consumed memory grows very very slowly.

In principle, you should get `MemoryError` at some point whether it happens before your computer turns to dust is unclear. [CPython uses a continuous block of memory to store the digits](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/db2dc5e31cc8e309457d6dd0795b55acab79fbb4/Include/longintrepr.h#L74-L92) and therefore you may get the error even if there is RAM available but fragmented.

Your specific code shouldn't trigger it but in general you could also get [`OverflowError` if you try to construct an integer larger than `sys.maxsize` bytes](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/db2dc5e31cc8e309457d6dd0795b55acab79fbb4/Objects/longobject.c#L176-L203).

Comment: So, no spillage into pagefile then, because it would not be continuous.

Comment: @coding4fun: python doesn't care where the memory comes from. Whether OS uses pagefile or not is completely transparent for python. It looks like the algorithm is too slow to fill the memory anyway.